# testing if oEmbed field is empty fails

Tags: entries-field

I am using the 'oEmbed' plugin and I have an oEmbed field with the handle `videoUrl`.
I am trying to do something very basic - to test if the field is empty.

I am not sure why it fails. I have tried the following codes on an empty field but it keep rendering the content despite the fact that the field is empty...

```
{% if entry.videoUrl is not empty %}
    <div class="page orange">
        <div class="video">
            {{ craft.oembed.render(entry.videoUrl, {params: {title: 0, portrait: 0, byline: 0 }}) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

And also this one fails:

```
{% set video = entry.videoUrl %}
{% if video is defined and video is not empty %}
    <div class="page orange">
        <div class="video">
            {{ craft.oembed.render(entry.videoUrl, {params: {title: 0, portrait: 0, byline: 0 }}) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

And this one as well:

```
{% if entry.videoUrl|length %}
    <div class="page orange">
        <div class="video">
            {{ craft.oembed.render(entry.videoUrl, {params: {title: 0, portrait: 0, byline: 0 }}) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround to the problem.
Instead of testing the field itself, I am testing the `media` parameter.

```
{% if entry.videoUrl.media is not empty %}
    some code
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
{% set video = entry.videoUrl ?? null %}
{% if video %}
    <div class="page orange">
        <div class="video">
            {{ craft.oembed.render(video, {params: {title: 0, portrait: 0, byline: 0 }}) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

This will check if the entry is not null and not defined. If you want to do an empty check as well you can use:

```
{% set video = entry.videoUrl ??? null %}
{% if video %}
    <div class="page orange">
        <div class="video">
            {{ craft.oembed.render(video, {params: {title: 0, portrait: 0, byline: 0 }}) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

**note**: if you want the empty coalesce to work (`???`) it is included with SEOMatic if you have that, or you can install the free https://plugins.craftcms.com/empty-coalesce plugin.

It works a lot easier and nicer than to chain all those commands.

If you want it natively:

```
{% if entry.videoUrl is defined and entry.videoUrl is not empty and entry.videoUrl is not null %}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work... might be a problem with the plugin itself?